# How to use elements of tables in recurrence tables?

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I am trying to use a `List` inside a `RecurrenceTable`. Suppose I have the list `v = {1, x, Exp[x]}`, and I want to use elements of this list inside the recurrence table so I tried

```
RecurrenceTable[{u[1] == v[[1]],u[n] == v[[n]] - Sum[(Integrate[v[[n]]*u[j], {x, 0, 1}]/Integrate[u[j]^2, {x, 0, 1}]) u[j], {j, 1, n - 1}]}, u, {n, 1, 3}]
```

This gives me the error

> ```
> Part: The expression n cannot be used as a part specification.
> ```

How can I use `Part` successfully in a recurrence table? If it is useful it reads

`v[[n]]` as `{1, x, Exp[x]}[[n]]` which I can't figure out why since I ranged the indices of `n` from 1 to 10.

Comment: In a situation like this, don't use `RecurrenceTable[]`. Use `Table[]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple recursion:

```
ClearAll[u, v]
v[x_] := {1, x, Exp[x]}
u[x_][1] = v[x][[1]]
u[x_][n_] := v[x][[n]] - 
             Sum[(Integrate[v[x][[n]]*u[x][j], {x, 0, 1}]*u[x][j])/
                  Integrate[u[x][j], {x, 0, 1}], {j, 1, n - 1}]
```

Now `u[x][2]` gives

> `x - 1/2`

but `u[x][3]` gives `ComplexInfinity` because `Integrate[u[x][2], {x,0,1}]` in denominator is 0.

You can also use `Indexed[v[x], n]` instead of `Part` (`v[x][[n]]`).